# MultiLevel Inheritance in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

Hi I am trying to achieve a multilevel inheritance in Backbone.view but getting "extend" is not a fuction,

example :

```
var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({

})

var Child = Parent.extend({
   initialize:function(attributes) {

 }
})

var SubChild = Child.extend({ //Getting exception here
    initialize:function(attributes) {

  }    
})
```

Kindly guide me to resolve the issue.
Is it possible to do MultiLevel inheritance in BackBone.view?

Comment: `Backbone.view` with a capital V : `Backbone.View`

Comment: Yes tried but no luck, it's not working.

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere else, your code works as is https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dqbg0qL3/

Comment: @nikoshr let me recheck once again.

Answer (score -1):

Try following approach:

```
var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(attributes) {
       // ...
    }
});

var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({        
    child: new ChildView(),
    // ...
    initialize: function(attributes) {
       // ...  
    }        
});
```

You can play with that and move instantiation of ChildView to the ParentView `initialize` (constructor) method if needed or leave it as it is.

Comment: @PeterWagener original question is `Is it possible to do MultiLevel inheritance in BackBone.view?` - answer is `Yes!` and code is attached. What's the problem?

Comment: The question is asking if it is possible to extend an extension of `Backbone.View`.  I.e.  `Backbone.View --> SomeView --> SomeOtherView`.  I believe your answer is discussing a parent/child relationship, in terms of having one view (a parent) contain another view (a child).